# Flutter app crahses on open razorpay checkout getting error of unable to start checkoutActivity

Tags: android, flutter, razorpay

I am trying to resolve a problem while starting payment with Razorpay and getting below error when I hit the checkout button. I have tried all the option available on Google but nothing worked. I know this seems a duplicate question but I tried those options that's why I am putting this at last. Please help me with this thanks.

Razorpay package which I am using [razorpay_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/razorpay_flutter)

```
    Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/ForwardingOs;->getenv(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/com.package(31557): Opening an oat file without a class loader. Are you using the deprecated DexFile APIs?
D/AndroidRuntime(31557): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime(31557): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(31557): Process: com.package, PID: 31557
E/AndroidRuntime(31557): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.package/com.razorpay.CheckoutActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.razorpay.G__G_" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.package==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.package==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.package==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64]]
E/AndroidRuntime(31557):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3448)
E/AndroidRuntime(31557):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3595)
E/AndroidRuntime(31557):    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
E/AndroidRuntime(31557):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(31557):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(31557):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2147)
E/AndroidRuntime(31557):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
E/AndroidRuntime(31557):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
E/AndroidRuntime(31557):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7814)
E/AndroidRuntime(31557):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(31557):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
E/AndroidRuntime(31557):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
E/AndroidRuntime(31557): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.razorpay.G__G_" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.package==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.package==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.package==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64]]
E/AndroidRuntime(31557):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
E/AndroidRuntime(31557):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
E/AndroidRuntime(31557):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/AndroidRuntime(31557):    at com.razorpay.h__y_.G__G_(:1100)
E/AndroidRuntime(31557):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(31557):    at com.razorpay.a0.<clinit>(:204)
E/AndroidRuntime(31557):    at com.razorpay.a0.a(Unknown Source:0)
E/AndroidRuntime(31557):    at com.razorpay.d.f(:189)
E/AndroidRuntime(31557):    at com.razorpay.h.e(:427)
E/AndroidRuntime(31557):    at com.razorpay.y0.onCreate(:80)
E/AndroidRuntime(31557):    at com.razorpay.f.onCreate(:23)
E/AndroidRuntime(31557):    at com.razorpay.CheckoutActivity.onCreate(:8)
E/AndroidRuntime(31557):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7955)
E/AndroidRuntime(31557):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7944)
E/AndroidRuntime(31557):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
```

**Proguard Rules:**

```
   -keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}

-keepattributes JavascriptInterface
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-dontwarn com.razorpay.**
-keep class com.razorpay.** {*;}

-optimizations !method/inlining/*

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
  public void onPayment*(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing your  in android/app/build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.example.example"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```